# Перечисление параметров вложенного списка в одну строчку

Tags: ansible

В файле переменныйх vars имеется вот такая структура, по которой я настраиваю кластер glasterfs:

```
clusters:
  - name: glone
    replica: 2
    bricks:
      - hostname: node1
        path: /some/path1
      - hostname: node1
        path: /some/path2
      - hostname: node2
        path: /some/path1
      - hostname: node2
        path: /some/path2
```

Мне необходимо преобразовать эту структуру в задачу типа shell, которая в свою очередь выполнила бы команду:

```
gluster volume create glone replica 2 transport tcp <bricks>
```

,где "bricks" - это список в одну строку вида:

```
"node1:/some/path1 node2:/some/path1 node1:/some/path2 node2:/some/path2"
```

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использовать фильтр `json_query`:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ bricks | json_query(qry) | join(' ') }}"
  vars:
    qry: "[].{res: join(':',[hostname,path])} | [].res"
```

Документацию на JMESPath можно посмотреть здесь: http://jmespath.org/

Comment: Правльный ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Константин, спасибо большое за такой прямой и точный ответ на мой вопрос!
Я, немного подумав, подкорректировал ваш пример, адаптировал под себя и, в итоге, получил, действительно работающую задачу. Не ожидал того, что одной единственной задачей можно реализовать решение.

```
- name: gluster - create volume
  debug:
    msg: "gluster volume create {{ item.name }} replica {{ item.replica }} transport tcp {{ item.bricks | json_query(qry) | join(' ') }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ clusters }}"
  when:
    - clusters is defined
  vars:
    qry: "[].{res: join(':',[hostname,path])} | [].res"
```